# dot product of two quaternion rotations

Tags: java, math, rotation, quaternions, dot-product

I understand that the dot (or inner) product of two quaternions is the angle between the rotations (including the axis-rotation).  This makes the dot product equal to the angle between two points on the quaternion hypersphere.
I can not, however, find how to actually compute the dot product.

Any help would be appreciated!

current code:

```
public static float dot(Quaternion left, Quaternion right){
    float angle;

    //compute

    return angle;
}
```

Defined are Quaternion.w, Quaternion.x, Quaternion.y, and Quaternion.z.

Note: It can be assumed that the quaternions are normalised.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dot product for quaternions is simply the standard Euclidean dot product in 4D:

```
dot = left.x * right.x + left.y * right.y + left.z * right.z + left.w * right.w
```

Then the angle your are looking for is the `arccos` of the dot product (note that the dot product is not the angle): `acos(dot)`.

However, if you are looking for the relative rotation between two quaternions, say from `q1` to `q2`, you should compute the relative quaternion `q =  q1^-1 * q2` and then find the rotation associated with`q`.

Comment: @Luke:  I think you misunderstood this answer, which has two distinct parts.  The angle between quaternions that are treated as 4D vectors is the first part of this answer (the acos(dot) stuff).  The minimum angle rotation to take you from one quaternion to the other quaternion is the second part of this answer (which is different from the first part). Your answer is simply the details of this second part of the answer (i.e., getting the actual minimum rotation angle for the q listed above).

Comment: @JamesTursa the OP asked for "the angle between the rotations (including the axis-rotation)", in the form of a single scalar value -- not the quaternion that maps one quaternion to another -- so the second half of the answer is not actually answering the question. The first half of the answer is still incorrect, because the `acos` needs to be multiplied by 2, and you have to take the absolute value of the dot product before calling `acos` due to the quaternion "double cover" issue.

Comment: @Luke: I read the first half of this post as attempting to answer OP about treating the quaternions as simple 4D points on a hypersphere (OP's own words). So IMO the acos(dot) answer is correct for this specific request. The q stuff mentioned in this post is different from this (treating the quaternions as 3D rotations), and the poster notes this. The q stuff is exactly the same as your answer except there were no details given on how to actually find the rotation associated with q ... you supplied those details in your answer. So I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: But you cannot treat quaternions directly as 4d points, because both `q` and `-q` represent the exact same rotation, due to the "double cover issue". You have to first normalize so that the two quaternions are in the same hemisphere of the double cover space, and then you can treat them as 4d vectors, and the dot product will actually make sense then. I expanded my answer below to describe normalization against the double cover issue.

Answer (score 7):

### The "right way" to compute the angle between two quaternions

There is really no such thing as the angle between two quaternions, there is only the quaternion that takes one quaternion to another via multiplication. However, you can measure the total angle of rotation of that mapping transformation, by computing the difference between the two quaternions (e.g. `qDiff = q1.mul(q2.inverse())`, or your library might be able to compute this directly using a call like `qDiff = q1.difference(q2)`), and then measuring the angle about the axis of the quaternion (your quaternion library probably has a routine for this, e.g. `ang = qDiff.angle()`).

Note that you will probably need to fix the value, since measuring the angle about an axis doesn't necessarily give the rotation "the short way around", e.g.:

```
if (ang > Math.PI) {
    ang -= 2.0 * Math.PI;
} else if (ang < -Math.PI) {
    ang += 2.0 * Math.PI;
}
```

### Measuring the similarity of two quaternions using the dot product

**Update:** [See this answer instead](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90098/365886).

I assume that in the original question, the intent of treating the quaternions as 4d vectors is to enable a simple method for measuring the similarity of two quaternions, while still keeping in mind that the quaternions represent rotations. (The actual rotation mapping from one quaternion to another is itself a quaternion, not a scalar.)

Several answers suggest using the `acos` of the dot product. (First thing to note: the quaternions must be unit quaternions for this to work.) However, the other answers don't take into account the "double cover issue": both `q` and `-q` represent the exact same rotation.

Both `acos(q1 . q2)` and `acos(q1 . (-q2))` should return the same value, since `q2` and `-q2` represent the same rotation. However (with the exception of `x == 0`), `acos(x)` and `acos(-x)` do not return the same value. Therefore, on average (given random quaternions), `acos(q1 . q2)` will not give you what you expect half of the time, meaning that it will not give you a measure of the angle between `q1` and `q2`, assuming that you care at all that `q1` and `q2` represent rotations. So even if you only plan to use the dot product or `acos` of the dot product as a similarity metric, to test how similar `q1` and `q2` are in terms of the effect they have as a rotation, the answer you get will be wrong half the time.

More specifically, if you are trying to simply treat quaternions as 4d vectors, and you compute `ang = acos(q1 . q2)`, you will sometimes get the value of `ang` that you expect, and the rest of the time the value you actually wanted (taking into account the double cover issue) will be `PI - acos(-q1 . q2)`. Which of these two values you get *will randomly fluctuate between these values depending on exactly how `q1` and `q2` were computed!*.

To solve this problem, you have to normalize the quaternions so that they are in the same "hemisphere" of the double cover space. There are several ways to do this, and to be honest I'm not even sure which of these is the "right" or optimal way. They do all produce different results from other methods in some cases. Any feedback on which of the three normalization forms above is the correct or optimal one would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import org.joml.Quaterniond;
import org.joml.Vector3d;

public class TestQuatNorm {
    private static Random random = new Random(1);

    private static Quaterniond randomQuaternion() {
        return new Quaterniond(
                random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1, random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1,
                random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1, random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1)
                .normalize();
    }

    public static double normalizedDot0(Quaterniond q1, Quaterniond q2) {
        return Math.abs(q1.dot(q2));
    }

    public static double normalizedDot1(Quaterniond q1, Quaterniond q2) {
        return
            (q1.w >= 0.0 ? q1 : new Quaterniond(-q1.x, -q1.y, -q1.z, -q1.w))
            .dot(
               q2.w >= 0.0 ? q2 : new Quaterniond(-q2.x, -q2.y, -q2.z, -q2.w));
    }

    public static double normalizedDot2(Quaterniond q1, Quaterniond q2) {
        Vector3d v1 = new Vector3d(q1.x, q1.y, q1.z);
        Vector3d v2 = new Vector3d(q2.x, q2.y, q2.z);
        double dot = v1.dot(v2);
        Quaterniond q2n = dot >= 0.0 ? q2 
                : new Quaterniond(-q2.x, -q2.y, -q2.z, -q2.w);
        return q1.dot(q2n);
    }

    public static double acos(double val) {
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(Math.max(-1.0, Math.min(1.0, val))));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            var q1 = randomQuaternion();
            var q2 = randomQuaternion();

            double dot = q1.dot(q2);
            double dot0 = normalizedDot0(q1, q2);
            double dot1 = normalizedDot1(q1, q2);
            double dot2 = normalizedDot2(q1, q2);

            System.out.println(acos(dot) + "\t" + acos(dot0) + "\t" + acos(dot1)
                + "\t" + acos(dot2));
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that:

1. `acos` is known to not be very numerically accurate (given some worst-case inputs, up to half of the least significant digits can be wrong);
2. the implementation of `acos` is exceptionally slow in the JDK standard libraries;
3. `acos` returns `NaN` if its parameter is even slightly outside [-1,1], which is a common occurrence for dot products of even unit quaternions -- so you need to bound the value of the dot product to that range before calling `acos`. See this line in the code above:

```
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(Math.max(-1.0, Math.min(1.0, val))));
```

According to [this cheatsheet](http://www.neil.dantam.name/note/dantam-quaternion.pdf) Eq. (42), there is a more robust and accurate way of computing the angle between two vectors that replaces `acos` with `atan2` (although note that this does not solve the double cover problem either, so you will need to use one of the above normalization forms before applying the following):

```
ang(q1, q2) = 2 * atan2(|q1 - q2|, |q1 + q2|)
```

I admit though that I don't understand this formulation, since quaternion subtraction and addition has no geometrical meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Just NOTE: acos(dot) is very not stable from numerical point of view.

as was said previos, q = q1^-1 * q2 and than angle = 2*atan2(q.vec.length(), q.w)

Comment: Please compare with the `atan2` formulation in the cheatsheet I linked in my answer -- I don't understand the difference.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

Should it be 2 x acos(dot) to get the angle between quaternions.

Comment: Are you _sure_ about that? I think this is incorrect. Please double-check. (Reference: https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-quaternions/)

Comment: quaternion dot product will range from 1.0 to 0.0 whereas a 3d orientation vector dot product will range from 1.0 to -1.0 ..so doubling the arcos(dot) seems logical

Comment: @Isometriq For unit/rotation quaternions their dot product ranges \in `[-1...1]`. I too believe this is wrong. The accepted answer should be the correct one.

Comment: The dot product of two normalized vectors gives the cosine of the angle between the vectors, so `acos(dot)` is (almost) sufficient, and multiplying by 2 is not needed. However, what I think you're getting at is the double-cover problem: `q` and `-q` represent the same rotation. See my answer for details (and for why I said "(almost)").